# 3 copies in a git project?

Tags: git, repository

I think I have been seriously confused while reading the Git documents. It looks like I need to clone from the remote to the local, then make another copy from local to work space, then work on the work space copy. Then commit from work space copy to local repository copy, then push from local repository copy to remote copy. For a project I have to make 2 copies in my local computer. Am I correct? Thanks a lot

Comment: When you say copy I think you mean branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to mix-up the concepts of repository and working copy.

A repository is the project with all of its history in entirety. It does NOT include necessarily anything checked-out or readable - it's a bare repository.
In your local repository you usually check-out a revision, the revision which you want to work on; by default the most recent revision is checked-out after a clone from the remote. Thus your working copy which is associated with your local repository, contains the files as they look like in the checked-out revision. Usually the repository and working copy is structured like

```
myrepo               <--- this is the dir which contains the working copy
 |- .git             <--- the actual repository. A hidden directory as a sub-dir of the working copy
```

You usually operate on the repository and the working copy with the usual git commands when within the *myrepo* directory. You can change the default behaviour and even create several check-outs from the same local repository.

Comment: Excellent, thanks I think I am finally cleared out with the terms: local repository & working copy. They are associated & local repository has metadata about the working copy. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, a working copy is always associated with a repository. Git stores the state of the working copy/ies also somewhere in the .git dir (though that technically is not part of the repository itself in the strictest sense of the word 'repository' - as a repository can exist without working copy).